# Using registers and variables in 8086 asm programming

Tags: assembly, x86-16, cpu-registers, instruction-set

I am starting to get to grips with asm programming but I feel I am missing something regarding the use of registers to store variables.
The issue that I have is that some instructions will modify other registers for internal reasons. In some cases I have used these registers to store application logic.
Is there any golden rule for how to use registers?

For example: the following code changes the `DX` register and wipes out my current variable (also in `DX`).

```
mov ax, 04h
mov bx, 02h
mul bx
```

I did not want nor state that I wanted the `DX` register to get wiped out. What's going on here?

Comment: That's just the way it is. You have to learn what all the instructions (or the ones you intend to use anyway) do, and take that into account when writing your code. In the case you've shown, the most significant word of the 32-bit product `ax*bx` will be stored in `dx`, which is stated in [Intel's manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) (`MUL r/m16   Unsigned multiply (DX:AX ← AX ∗ r/m16).`)

Comment: Use `imul ax, bx` if you don't want the full result. But that form of imul was new with 386 (https://ulukai.org/ecm/insref.htm#insIMUL)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to assembly language programming. The short answer is pick the values that are manipulated most often. This is the rule compilers use for register allocation. They score usages numerically with heuristic values, then put the best scores in registers until there are no more.

In 8086 assembler, you have a very small number of registers, and many of them have special purposes. You've discovered one: `mul` and `div` implicitly use `ax` and `dx`. Just think of the `mul` instruction as `mul dx:ax, operand`, and you'll see what's going on. That makes your life harder, but the architecture designer doesn't care much. She's trying primarily to make the hardware implementation small and fast.

Studying x86 assembly with 32-bit operands will make your life easier in this regard because lots of the special usages go away. For example, there are 2-operand `mul` instructions that take a destination register and source just like `add`.

Rules of thumb:

- Put variables used within loop bodies in registers. For nested loops, start with the innermost and work outward.
- For computations that require special purpose usages: multiply and divide (implicitly use ax and dx as operands), variable shift counts (need cx), address calculations (need bx, si, or di), etc., try to arrange for the required number to be in the necessary register during the previous computation rather than adding an extra mov. This is called register targeting.
- Look at assembly generated by a good compiler for new ways of thinking. Many person-years of expert thought go into the strategies they use. You can learn from them.

Comment: I have been using the stack to store (push/pop) but it felt wrong to me as it's a wasted operation. Understanding that this is a fundamental concern when planing the code helps me out; as it's not something I am doing wrong. Ta all

Comment: On those older x86 16 bit and 32 bit CPU´s up to Intel Pentium 3 / AMD Athlon XP the combination of a push and pop instruction executes some tiks slower, than a combination of a mov and mov instruction on a known memory location, example in the data segment and it is always easier for to get the content back independently from the stack pointer.

Comment: "...the architecture designer doesn't care much. **She**'s trying..." Why the shift from *He* to *She* ? I'm not a native English speaker myself, so has something changed in the English language or is this now considered the more politically correct way?

Comment: @SepRoland: Yes, purposely using "she" for hypothetical / unknown people, especially in jobs that are stereotypically male, is one standard way of phrasing things without using singular "they" or the traditional "he" assumption.  These days it's generally more encouraged to use "they" for such cases.  "They" is more inclusive (gender can be non-binary), and often reads more naturally (especially when in practice the person is most likely male).  Part of the "reading naturally" comes from singular "they" gaining use even for some specific people, not just unknown people.

Comment: Yeah. I'm old and have done way too much writing in my life. I use "they" all day at work. I know it's current practice and all the reasons why. And I agree with them. But  using "they" when a singular pronoun is intended still grates as finger nails on a blackboard. So I revert now and then to the older style. No offense intended.

Answer (score 2):

Instructions that compute function like mul need a register to store the result of the function. DX is primarily used for that.

You will not be able to store all your variables in registers. You'll need to use the heap and the stack to store variables as well.

The stack is particularly useful for temporary storage of variables. Your code will often look like this:

```
// some variable is in ax
// needing the register for something else now, pushing current variable to the stack

push ax

// put some new value into ax
// ... do some computations with it ...
// now we need the old value back in ax

pop ax
```